# Notation for the "image" or "codomain" of the function that maps a subset $A \subseteq X$ to it's cardinal number, referencing the set $X$ directly?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, terminology

What is the best notation for the "image" or "codomain" of the function that maps a subset $A \subseteq X$ to it's cardinal number, referencing the set $X$ directly?

Once a set $X$ has been chosen, there is a function $card$ that with domain $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that maps subsets to cardinalities.  However it is presently unclear to me what do label the codomain of this function.

Typically $|X|$ is used to denote the cardinality of a set $X$.  But it is unclear how to label the proper of *all* cardinalities of subsets of a given set $X$, in a way that references $X$ .  Or in other words, the proper set of cardinalities which are less than or equal to $|X|$, the cardinality of the set $X$.

Is it best to simply write:

- Define $card: \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ by $card(A) = |A|$ for each $A \subseteq X$.

?

Note the choice of the notation $|\mathcal{P}(X)|$ as the codomain of $card$.  Is the powerset notation $|\mathcal{P}(X)|$ a good choice for this codomain?

Consider the cases where $X = \mathbb{N}$, $X = \mathbb{R}$, or more generically where $X$ is an algebraic structure such as a group.  Is aleph notation here best?  Is it avoidable?

**Edit:**

So, focusing on the case where $X = \mathbb{R}$ may I write:

Define $card_\mathbb{R}: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \vert\mathbb{R}\vert + 1$ by $card_{\mathbb{R}}(A) = |A|$ for each $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

so that

$card_\mathbb{R}(\emptyset) = 0$,

$card_\mathbb{R}(\{1,7, 42\}) = 3$,

$card_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{Z}) = \aleph_0$, and

$card_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathfrak{c}$

?

There are a few colliding notations, the vertical bar notation: $\vert \cdot \vert$ (commonly seen in abstract algebra) and the $card()$ notation (as in Real Analysis by Gerald B Folland, where it is is not defined alone, but only as part of an expression such as $card(X) = card(Y)$).  I wish to define a function as a restriction of "function-class" [as in Notes on Logic and Set Theory by P.T. Johnstone] $card: V \rightarrow V$ by restricting its domain to to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, which should give a proper function in the sense of set theory, with a domain and a codomain and, hopefully, a notation for each which clearly distinguishes the function from it's codomain.

Counting subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ arises naturally in the formalization of simple ideas such as the "vertical line test" (see below).  In the textbooks I've refered to (Dummit & Foote, etc) the question of the codomain here is often glossed over even though in most other situations the codomain of a function is explicitly given a notation, or at least there is one available in needed.

The purpose of this notation is for this context, in defining $v_a$: [Given a relation, how is the set of values for which the" vertical line test" fails usually described and what is the notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651109/given-a-relation-how-is-the-set-of-values-for-which-the-vertical-line-test-fa).

Comment: If $A \subseteq X$ then $\text{card}(A)\leq\text{card}(X)$, so the codomain is $|X|$, not $|\mathcal{P}(X)|$. And this only makes sense  if a cardinal is used to label the set of cardinals up to it. There is no "best notation" without a purpose, which is unclear from the post, what is this notation used for? One can simply denote it $\text{card}_X$ if needed.

Comment: Why do you need a domain and codomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the set of cardinals less than or equal to $|X|$ — that is, the set of all cardinals less than $|X|^+$, the cardinal successor of $|X|$.

*In case that's not clear*: Of course $|A| \leq |X|$ for any $A \subseteq X$. Conversely, for every cardinal $\lambda \leq |X|$ there's a subset $A$ of $X$ with $|A| = \lambda$ — namely, $f^{-1}[\lambda]$ where $f\colon X \to |X|$ is any bijection.

The range of $A\mapsto |A|$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is $\mathrm{Card} \cap |X|^+$, and if you call it that you'll be understood. If you need to refer to this set frequently, you might define a shorthand for it. For example, if you declare that $\mathrm{Card}_{\leq \kappa} = \mathrm{Card} \cap \kappa^+$ by definition, then the set you want to denote would be $\mathrm{Card}_{\leq |X|}$.

Comment: Edited to actually answer OP's question, and for clarity.